How to create a global store like reduxt toolkit or zustand using react context api?
When you don't want use redux toolkit, zustand or other tools but want to use react context api for global state management of your frontend app. How will make a global store with react context api ?

So I have found an easy and simple way to make a global store of react app using react context api and it's hooks like useContext, createContext. The example bellow is using typescript. For better understanding react context with typescript you can visit this link

First create a global context provider and pass the states for the whole app that will be used
import { createContext, useContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState, PropsWithChildren} from "react";

type AppState = {
  count: number,
  setCount: Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>;
}

const AppContext = createContext<AppState| undefined>(undefined)

const AppContextProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({children}) => {
 const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);

   <AppContext.Provider value={{
       count,
       setCount
    }}>
      {children}
   </AppContext.Provider>
}

const useAppStore = (): AppState => {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);

  if(!context){
    throw new Err('useAppStore must be called under AppContext.Provider')
   }

  return context;
}

return {AppContextProvider, useAppStore};



Wrap your root app component with AppContextProvider
 <AppContextProvider>
  <App/>
 </AppContextProvider>



Then in your desired component use the hook called useAppStore. Let's say you are making a counter app. In Count component you can do like bellow
  import {useAppStore} from '@/store'; // add your path 

  const Count = () => {

   const {count, setCount} = useAppStore();

   return (
    <div>
       {count}
       <button onClick={()=> setCount(count+1)}>Count up</button>
    </div>
  )
 }








